# Loading a template from an external file in CanJS

Tags: canjs, canjs-view

If I add below code in my index.html then it's working fine but I want to define in external file and then I want to load it with `can.view`.

```
<script type="text/mustache" id="todosList">
     {{#todos}}
          <li>{{description}}</li>
     {{/todos}}
</script>
```

If I create separate html file how do I load a template from it?

Answer (score 1):

`can.view` can directly load templates from a URL. [From the can.view documentation](http://canjs.com/docs/can.view.html#section_LoadingTemplates):

> #### Loading templates from a url
>
> To load from a url, simply pass the location of the template to
>   can.view. The location of the template needs an extension that matches
>   the type of template:
>
> ```
> document.getElementById('recipes')   
>       .appendChild(can.view('templates/recipes.ejs', recipeData ) )
> ```
>
> Note: If you are using RequireJS, the URL will be relative to its baseUrl.

In your case, if you named your file `todos.mustache` and it was in the `templates` directory, it would look like this:

> ```
> document.getElementById('todos')   
>       .appendChild(can.view('todos.mustache', recipeData ) )
> ```

Comment: Well, I'm not using text/ejs template. what extension should I give for text/mustache template?

Comment: @JayShukla I updated the answer. A mustache file has a `mustache` file extension.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('target-element').html(can.view('todosList', todolist-data))
```

This is the syntax to load external template in canJS.

Comment: I know this. It's working fine when I define above declaration of template inside index.html but I want separate file for todosList template and then want load using can.view...

Comment: You should just be able to reference the external file instead of the script tag id: `$('target-element').html(can.view('path/to/todosList.mustache', todolist-data))`